# UWP AppUriHandler doesn't work

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to test new API from Windows 10 anniversary update and have a problem with AppUriHandler. I just do everything ok, it works if I input URI via WIN+R cmd but if it's link in a browser - it doesn't work. Does some additional rules exist for open app via browser link ? I know about JSON, I have tried to create my own website, added JSON but doesnt work. But honestly I want to create app for external website and if user installed my app he will able to open this website in my app. Or Microsoft care about website owner's traffic and I can't to do that?

Comment: I've also tried the API, the result was same with @FoxNet. Then... I've noticed that MS said that it works with ShellExecuteEx or LaunchUriAsync. They does not mention about Web browsers... hmmm... It's by design, maybe...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking

Comment: yes. So as I said below @Jay-Zuo we need JSON and packageFamilyName wich as I understood we can get via Store. It's lifebuoy for website owners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pnp0a03 said, this behavior is by design. See the [**Note**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking#test-it-web-validation) in [Support web-to-app linking with app URI handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking):

> **Note:** If you click a link in the Microsoft Edge browser, it will not launch your app but will take you to your website.

When we click the link in the Microsoft Edge browser, Windows suppose we want to use browser to open this link. But in other places, if we open the link, it will open the app instead of opening the browser. For example, using a `HyperlinkButton`:

```xml
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="https://msdn.microsoft.com/">msdn.microsoft.com</HyperlinkButton>
```

If you have deployed [Association launching sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AssociationLaunching), clicking the `HyperlinkButton` will open this app for you.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Yes, I saw this sample. But the biggest problem is when we want to create new app for foreign website, because native client is bad or generally does not exist. So as I understood, without JSON we don't have a chance to get redirect from browser to our app. I think it's safe for website owners because we're stealing traffic and they won't get money from advertisement

Comment: @FoxNet Yeah, you are right. The JSON file is necessary and it must be uploaded to an https server. This ensures that only valid apps can open content on the website. But please note that all sideloaded apps with AppUriHandlers will have validated links for the host on install. You do not need to have a JSON file uploaded to test the feature.

Comment: I have a concern about the design of side-loaded apps, from the view of security. In this case, developer can create a redirect link from any Website to their uwp apps. For example, the developer can make a redirect from online banking website to their apps. Yes, OS shows the confirmation dialog before launch the app, but there are potentially risk. ..But here is a stack overflow :) Is not a feedback hub.. ok...

Comment: It seems that the creators update support the appurihandler with Edge browser. Good news :) https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/01/12/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-15007-pc-mobile/